# does hibernate support partitioning?

Tags: java, hibernate

I used [Hibernate3](http://www.hibernate.org/) and Oracle database in my project and now i need to change my db from oracle to Microsoft SQl Server.

There is [Partition Table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c12parti.htm)s in oracle which is not available in Microsoft SQl Server.
does anyone know if hibernate have a built-in support for table partitioning or not?

It seems implementing such a features in hibernate isn't a big problem.
if there is no built-in table partitioning in hibernate can i implement my own table partitioning? -- any hint?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345146(v=sql.90).aspx - SQL Server does have partitioning.

Comment: i use mssql 2000 doesn't support partitioning! beside i need a cross database solution! maybe in futher we have to switch to other db!

Comment: SQL 2K will be completely out of support in a couple month. If you're changing databases, change to something that's not already obsolete. (And as regards partitioning or advanced features like that, each database vendor has slightly different approaches. If you want performance, don't try portable.)

Comment: what i look for is a hibernate solution! to work across different db vendors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MSSQL 2000 doesn't support database partitioning. But you can try some alternative way like hibernate sharding. Please learn [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-javadev2-11/) from ibm for hibernate sharding.

Answer (score 0):

I think the way it was done before partitioning became a feature was to create a table for each partition and then create a view that represented the complete table, buy doing a union across all partition tables.

Should be dowable in Sql Server as well